# How to set write proper permission on a openshift container?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I am deploying a java app but it requires write permission, and I want to know what is approved way of doing that? Now I am just making a new docker image which takes the old image and adds permission to the folder in which the writes need to happen:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /application && \
    chmod -R g=u /application

USER 1001
RUN chown -R 1001:0 /application

RUN chmod 775 /application
```

But in this way, I would have to make a docker image every time I don't have enough permission, so this does not seem very efficient to me. Another way I thought of maybe making a initContainer in which I make the folder and give it the required permissions, then connect that to the actual container with a volume, but not only this requires for me to give root permission:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
```

The config also balloons in size, and currently it does not work.

Comment: Can you create a volume of some sort (maybe an `emptyDir` volume if the data doesn't need to persist) and mount that into your image?  It should be a single specific directory that only contains data and nothing else; the volume mount will hide any image content that may have been in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are fundamentally running into the issue that containers, by their very nature, are immutable. If you want write permissions, then the data you are writing has to be placed *somewhere*. And it can't be to the image itself since images don't change.

The correct way to handle the situation will depend on what data you are writing. The simplest case is "[emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir)" where your image mounts a directory on the host and the data is written there. This is essentially creating disposable storage, where you can write data but the data isn't guaranteed to survive the pod being recreated.

If that isn't sufficient, then look into the storage documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/storage/index.html . Depending on where you are running OpenShift there's lots of options about how to allocate storage to your container.

Comment: Yes, this solves the issue I had, but a new one appeared, that being that I don't just need to create the folder, but give it write permissions because inside the folder many other folders and files are created,